# Use express-ntlm authentication to auth to TFS api

Tags: express, tfs, ntlm, express-ntlm

Using `express` and `express-ntlm`, how can I create an `http://localhost:3000/api/bug/` endpoint that creates a bug for me in TFS by hitting the TFS api?

I can do this using `request-ntlm-promise` right now and this is how I do it.

```
const ntlm = require('request-ntlm-promise');

const ntlmOptions = {
  username: 'myUserName',
  password: 'myPassword',
  url: 'http://tfsinstance/collection/project/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=4.1',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'
  }
};

const tfsBugObject =[{
  'op': 'add',
  'path': '/fields/System.Title',
  'value': 'Test title'
}, {
  'op': 'add',
  'path': '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.SystemInfo',
  'value': 'Test system info'
}, {
  'op': 'add',
  'path': '/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps',
  'value': 'test reproduction steps'
}];

ntlm.post(ntlmOptions, tfsBugObject).then((response) => { return res.send(response); });
```

The problem is that I must provide a username and password in in `ntlmOptions` object. Doing this doesn't create the bug in TFS as the current user hitting the express API but instead creates the bug as the user 'myUserName'.

Using the `express-ntlm` package, is it possible to do an `http.post` to `http://tfsinstance/collection/project/...` using the NTLM credentials returned from that package?

TFS requires authentication in order for one to use the API.

Using `express-ntlm` I was hoping that I could do the following.

```
const express = require('express');
const ntlm = require('express-ntlm');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

app.use(ntlm({ domain: 'mydomain', domaincontroller: 'ldap://domaincontroller' });
```

then

```
httpOptions = {
    protocol: 'http',
    hostname: 'tfsinstance',
    pathname: '/collection/project/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=4.1',
    port: 8080,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'
    }
};

app.post('/report/bug', (req, res, next) => {
    const request = http.request(httpOptions, (response => {
        response.on('data', data => {
            // return response from TFS through express to user
        });
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`express-ntlm` acts as a proxy between a client and a domain controller. So the domain controller will handle the authentication with the client and `express-ntlm` just acts as a man in the middle until the authentication was successful.

If you can use some kind of API user and use `express-ntlm` to just get the correct username and pass it to the TFS API that would be the easiest way to do, otherwise I would suggest you to create your own proxy between your client and the TFS API.